# @ApiResponse swagger springfox - use of custom response container

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I am trying to display a custom container as a success response in swagger. I am unable to describe the desired model for this

```
@ApiResponse (code = 200, message = "Successfully retrieved report info", response = PagedResponse.class
```

THis PagedResponseInfo is actually a custom collection

```
public class PagedResponse<T> {

    private long page;
    private long pageSize;
    private long totalRecords;
    private List<T> records;
}
```

How do I specify the container for this if it were to contain a collection of **Report** objects in it? Could someone help me out please? I use springfox swagger -2.9.2 in spring boot

Comment: In your controller you have ResponseEntity<List<PagedResponse>> ?

Comment: The controller is with the following signature -  **public PagedResponse<ReportInfo> getReports**

Comment: So making it a ResponseEntity<List<PagedResponse>> is not the right approach to solve my problem. The PagedResponse in itself acts as a collection of Reports (list of Reports  object). So in my @ApiResponse i have to find a way of addressing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `responseContainer` attribute in the `@ApiResponse` annotation.

> ```
> /**
>  * Declares a container wrapping the response.
>  * <p>
>  * Valid values are "List", "Set" or "Map". Any other value will be ignored.
>  */
> String responseContainer() default "";
> ```

The value `List` is what you are looking for. It will wrap your `PagedResponse<ReportInfo>` in a container.

```
@ApiResponse(
    code = 200,
    message = "Successfully retrieved report info",
    response = PagedResponse.class,
    responseContainer = "List")
```